# Call to a member function mysqli_fetch_object() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando um sistema de likes e atualmente ele estava conectando com Mysql, ai agora estou migrando pra Mysqli, mas ta dando um erro e não consigo resolver de jeito nenhum :(

conexao.php

```
<?php
$servidor = 'localhost';
$usuario = 'root';
$senha = '';
$banco = 'meu_banco';

$con = mysqlI_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
?>
```

funcao.php

```
<?php
function get_artigos(){
    $artigos = array();
    $selecionar = "SELECT artigo_id, titulo, likes FROM artigos";

    while ($row->mysqli_fetch_object($selecionar)){
        $artigos[] = array(
            'id_artigo' => $row->artigo_id,
            'titulo' => $row->titulo,
            'likes' => $row->likes
        );
    }

    return $artigos;
 }


function verificar_clicado($id_artigo, $id_usuario){
    $id_artigo = (int)$id_artigo;
    $id_usuario = (int)$id_usuario;
    $verificar = "SELECT like_id FROM likes WHERE user_id = '$id_usuario'      AND artigo_id = '$id_artigo'");
    return (mysql_num_rows($verificar) >= 1) ? true : false;
}


function adicionar_like($id_artigo, $id_usuario){
    $id_artigo = (int)$id_artigo;
    $id_usuario = (int)$id_usuario;
    $atualizar_likes_post = "UPDATE artigos SET likes = likes+1 WHERE   artigo_id = '$id_artigo'";

    if($atualizar_likes_post){
        $inserir_like = "INSERT INTO likes (user_id, artigo_id) VALUES    ('$id_usuario','$id_artigo'");
        if($inserir_like){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;

        }
    }
}

function retornar_likes($id_artigo){
    $id_artigo = (int)$id_artigo;
    $selecionar_num_likes = "SELECT likes FROM artigos WHERE artigo_id =   $id_artigo";
    $fetch_likes = mysqli_fetch_object($selecionar_num_likes);
    return $fetch_likes->likes;
}
?>
```

Comment: `mysqlI_connect`, muda para letra pequena... Qual é o erro que dá?

Comment: acho que só alterando o mysqlI para mysqli já funciona, como o Sergio disse, pois o comando mysqli funciona da mesma forma que o mysql, porém aceita uma gama maior de serviços e opções

Comment: dica* 
Não coloca os parâmetros da sua conexão onde todos possam ver, deixa sempre como se fosse usar o padrão de testes no pc.
Ex: ('localhost', 'root', '', 'local_db')

Comment: @MuriloGambôa obrigada pela dica, coloquei o i em minusculo mas o mesmo erro continua aparecendo :(

Comment: Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 3):

Seu problema é porque você está chamando a função: `mysqli_fecth_object()`, com um 
  parâmetro que deveria ser passado para a função: `mysqli_query()`. por exemplo na função `getArtigos()`, está assim:

```
$selecionar = "SELECT artigo_id, titulo, likes FROM artigos";
while($row->mysqli_fetch_object($selecionar)){ }
```

Quando deveria estar assim:

```
$selecionar = "SELECT artigo_id, titulo, likes FROM artigos";
$resultado = mysqli_query($con, $selecionar);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($resultado)){ /*seu código aqui.*/ }
```

Você também está repetindo este erro nas funções:`retornar_likes()` e `verificar_clicado()`.
Alem disso você está misturando o código da versão orientada a objetos com o estilo procedural. Link para referência: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp